# preg_split with array delimiters with comma not split the array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I have an array with a list in an array and I have to split to find next a value

```
$artista_inserito = 'DEN HARROW';
$tutti_artisti_data_ora = [
    ['time_artisti' => '18:31:00', 'artista_artisti' => 'LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW', 'data_artisti' => '2020-04-09'],
    ['time_artisti' => '18:32:00', 'artista_artisti' => 'J BALVIN', 'data_artisti' => '2020-04-09'],
    ['time_artisti' => '18:33:00', 'artista_artisti' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS VS. J BALVIN', 'data_artisti' => '2020-04-08'],
    ['time_artisti' => '18:34:00', 'artista_artisti' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN', 'data_artisti' => '2020-04-09'],
    ['time_artisti' => '18:35:00', 'artista_artisti' => 'J BALVIN, DEN HARROW', 'data_artisti' => '2020-04-09'],
];
//here a list of delimiter
$databaseDelimiters = array('FEAT', 'feat', 'FT', 'ft', '+', 'AND', 'and', 'E', 'e', 'VS', 'vs', 'FEAT.', 'feat.', 'FT.', 'ft.', 'VS.', 'vs.', ',', '&', 'X', 'x', ', ', ',');

$artistDelimiters = '~ (?:' . implode('|', array_map(function ($v) {
    return preg_quote($v, '~');
}, $databaseDelimiters)) . ') ~';

$artists = array_flip(preg_split($artistDelimiters, $artista_inserito));
$result = [];
$autore_duplicato_stringa = '';
foreach ($tutti_artisti_data_ora as $row) {
    foreach (preg_split($artistDelimiters, $row['artista_artisti']) as $artist) {
// print the output with every artist
        echo $artist . '<br>';
    }
}
```

at now the output is $artista_artisti split by delimiters

```
LUIS RODRIGUEZ
DEN HARROW
J BALVIN
THE BLACK EYED PEAS
J BALVIN
THE BLACK EYED PEAS
J BALVIN
J BALVIN, DEN HARROW
```

what's wrong?
the last row must be

```
J BALVIN
DEN HARROW
```

why the comma is not recognized?
thanks

Comment: What is `$artista_inserito`?

Comment: Hi, it is a string to find in the array. but it is a next function

Comment: It is due to `$artistDelimiters` having spaces between the preg delimiters `~` and your list of split strings. `~ (?:FEAT|feat|FT|ft|\+|AND|and|E|e|VS|vs|FEAT\.|feat\.|FT\.|ft\.|VS\.|vs\.|,|&|X|x|, |,) ~`

Comment: So the delimiters have to have spaces around them, and there's no spaces around the `,`.

Comment: Could you remove the parts of the snippet that are unrelated to the problem?

Comment: I can make your code work if I change all the delimiters like `'FEAT'`  into `' FEAT '` with surrounding space and remove the outer spaces near the `~`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I cannot remove the spaces between the preg delimiters ~

Comment: You're going to drive yourself crazy trying to use regular expressions to parse free-form human-created text. Humans don't follow simple patterns consistently.

Comment: @pette Why not? Like he said, you can add the spaces where needed to the delimiters instead of putting them around all the delimiters.

Comment: @pette If you redefine your array like `$databaseDelimiters = array(' FEAT ',  ' feat ', ' FT ', ' ft ',....` with spaces embedded, the code will work.

Comment: @Barmar I think there was an other solution without change the delimiters for only 1 elements

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski si I have to change the function `$artistDelimiters = '~(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function ($v) {
    return preg_quote($v, '~');
}, $databaseDelimiters)) . ')~';`

Comment: @pette - yes, if you put spaces on the array elements you must remove the extra spaces from the `array_map()`

Comment: and change delimiters with `$databaseDelimiters = array(' FEAT ', ' feat ', ' FT ', ' ft ', ' + ', ' AND ', ' and ', ' E ', ' e ', ' VS ', ' vs ', ' FEAT. ', ' feat. ', ' FT. ', ' ft. ', ' VS. ', ' vs. ', ' , ', ' & ', ' X ', ' x ', ', ');`

Comment: I'll put the working solution below

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks, it works! would you put the right solution or I put the solution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surrounding whitespace near the regex `~` delimiters is interfering with the `,` because it expects a trailing space. You can place spaces around the delimiting terms that require them, and remove spaces from the outer regex `~`.

```
// Put spaces only where needed
$databaseDelimiters = array(' FEAT ',  ' feat ', ' FT ', ' ft ', ' + ', ' AND ', ' and ', ' E ', ' e ', ' VS ', ' vs ', ' FEAT. ', ' feat. ', ' FT. ',  ' ft. ', ' VS. ', ' vs. ', ',', '&', ' X ', ' x ', ', ', ',');

// Remove the outer spaces from the map function
$artistDelimiters = '~(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function ($v) {
//-------------------^^^
    return preg_quote($v, '~');
}, $databaseDelimiters)) . ')~';
//--------------------------^^^
```

This produces output like:

```
LUIS RODRIGUEZ <br> DEN HARROW<br>J BALVIN<br>THE BLACK EYED PEAS<br>J BALVIN<br>THE BLACK EYED PEAS<br>J BALVIN<br>J BALVIN<br> DEN HARROW<br>
```

You can `trim()` the individual values before appending the `<br>` if necessary.